# How do I open up a ServerSocket in my android application?

Tags: android, serversocket

Ok so I am doing something that seems like it should be very easy. I am basically trying to open up a ServerSocket connection and then wait for the client to connect.

Here is my code.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6543);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

Whenever my code hits, serverSocket.accept();, I am throwing the following exception.

```
bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
```

So obviously my next step was to check and see if another port would work, it did not. Next I restarted the device and tried running the app and I got the same exception. I have given my app INTERNET permission and the device is rooted.

Here are my network interfaces that show up.

```
lo: ::1%1
lo: 127.0.0.1
eth0: //IPV6 address 
eth0: 192.168.1.127
```

EDIT 1

Here is the serverSocket object info that I get when debugging.

```
ServerSocket[addr=192.168.1.121/192.168.1.121,port=0,localport=1234]
```

EDIT 2

I have the following available constructors in my ServerSocket

```
new ServerSocket(int port)
new ServerSocket(int port, int backlog)
new ServerSocket(int port, int backlog, InetAddress localAddress)
```

I tried using the 3rd constructor and same exception.

```
new ServerSocket(4567, 0, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
```

Comment: Right, let me know how it goes!

Comment: Yeah I got nothing in there documentation, also I turned around and tested this on a phone and the emulator and I received the same exception.

Comment: If you remove  serverSocket.accept()  does it work?

Comment: Yes, no exception will be thrown. It only throws that when it hits serverSocket.accept(). But then the app doesn't block until a client connection is received either.

Comment: I've never had that problem, what's the exception type?

Comment: It is a java.net.BindException.

Comment: Not sure.. I've only ever gotten that when I bind to an already used port number.

Comment: Ok I put a breakpoint right on the serverSocket.accept() and looked at the serverSocket object. Check this out, ServerSocket[addr=192.168.1.121/192.168.1.121,port=0,localport=1234]. Shouldn't port be my port number instead of 0.

Comment: Yes, totally. That looks odd. Try another constructor.
new ServerSocket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),8888) //should be the correct syntax.

Comment: Interesting I do not have that constructor.

Comment: Yeah sorry try this: new ServerSocket(int port, int backlog, InetAddress)

Comment: That still didn't get me. This is nerve wrecking.

Comment: Can you try it outside Android? A simple Java program..

Comment: Works flawlessly on my Windows machine.

Comment: Something to do with Android then? I have no time to try it unfortunately.

Comment: It has to be, time to research hard core I guess

Comment: Good luck, if you find the soln ping me ;)

Comment: Ok I finally got it fixed but don't understand why. I updated my question.

Comment: What was the problem? There doesn't seem to be any update to your question.

Comment: Just finished updating took me a second :)

Comment: You should put that as your answer. +1 and kudos to solving it at least. Must be a thread safety thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I finally figured out why my application was throwing an exception and if anyone has some feedback on this or would like to provide an answer as to why this was happening. I would greatly appreciate it.

So in my Thread that I created I need to postback to the main thread to update some TextView's based upon what was happening with the server connection. Well since I can't update the main thread from my self created thread I needed to add a Handler object to that Thread in order to update the UI. Removing that Handler completely allowed my application to successfully create the ServerSocket without throwing an exception.

Does the Handler somehow run the code before hand or what was happening here?

The code.

```
RemoteServerRunnable test = new RemoteServerRunnable();
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(test);
test.start();
```